# Websphere verbose classloading of certain packages

Tags: java, websphere, classloader, websphere-7, verbose

In websphere 7 is there any way to limit the verbose classloading to log only classes from certain packages. Say I want to see only classes which are loaded from package **com.mycompany.*** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified in the [Class-loader runtime diagnostics](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.60/diag/tools/class_load_runtime.html) section of [IBM SDK and Runtime Environment Java Technology Edition Version 6](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v6r0/index.jsp) (Which is the Java WebSphere uses)

You can set the `-Dibm.cl.verbose=<class_expression>` variable in order to do what you want, in your case `-Dibm.cl.verbose=com.mycompany.*`

In WebSphere Admin Console under `Application servers > server1 > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine` instead of checking `Verbose class loading` just add the variable to `Generic JVM arguments` and that should do the trick